# EU citizen, non-EU spouse, work travel visa Australia?

Tags: working-visas, australia, brazilian-citizens, eu-spouses

I am wondering if it is possible for my spouse to get a work holiday visa for NZ or Australia too?

If not what would our alternative options be?

She is from Brazil, I am from Ireland we currently live here. She would need to be here another 3 years before being eligible for an Irish passport, problem is I will be over 30 by then and not eligible for the work holiday visa.

Comment: EU citizenship and EU rules are irrelevant. Australia does not offer WHV to Brazilian citizens but NZ does. The [Australian website](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/417.aspx) suggests that it's possible for your partner to come with you but it's unclear to me if she needs to be from an eligible country as well. But I don't think Irish citizens are eligible in Australia either.

Comment: @Relaxed: The site says *"Your partner can accompany you to Australia, but they will need to apply for their own visa."* which means the partner's visa application would be considered independently, and therefore for a working holiday visa must be from an eligible country.

Comment: @GregHewgill That's one interpretation and the reason why I wrote that it's unclear but I don't think it's so obvious as you seem to imply. The question is whether some sort of partner visa is available or not. They would obviously need to get a visa of their own (as is almost universally the case) but the criteria could be different.

Comment: Irish citizens really are eligible in Australia, I somehow missed it in the list.

Answer (score 4):

For New Zealand, Brazilian citizens are eligible for a working holiday visa: http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/workingholiday/brazilwhs.htm However, there are limited places available:

> The quota opened on 3 September 2013 and was filled within a short time. Further places will become available in September 2014.

Unfortunately, Brazilian citizens are **not** eligible for a working holiday visa from Australia: https://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/working-holiday/visa-options.htm